# maven is not creating META-INF for spring boot project

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

When I build my Spring boot project, it creates an target folder and
target/classes also, but it doesn't create any META-INF. I have also included dependency -

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.3.2</version>
<configuration>
    <archive>
        <index>true</index>
        <manifest>
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
        </manifest>
        <manifestEntries>
            <mode>development</mode>
            <url>${project.url}</url>
            <key>value</key>
        </manifestEntries>
    </archive>
</configuration>
```

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_add_resources_to_my_JAR

Answer (score 5):

Two ways to do it.

1. Form the [maven-jar-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/) documentation :

> Please note that the following parameter has been completely removed
>   from the plugin configuration:

```
useDefaultManifestFile
```

> If you need to define your own MANIFEST.MF file you can simply achieve
>   that via Maven Archiver configuration like in the following example:

```
<configuration>
    <archive>
        <manifestFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
    </archive>
</configuration>
```

where in you can place your `MANIFEST.MF` under `src/main/resources/META-INF` folder of your project. The command

```
mvn clean package
```

would build the project jar with the src/main/resources by default.

2. The notes at [usage of the plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/manifest-customization.html) states that

> Starting with version 2.1, the maven-jar-plugin uses Maven Archiver
>   3.1.1. This means that it no longer creates the Specification and Implementation details in the manifest by default. If you want them
>   you have to say so explicitly in your plugin configuration.

Which can be done using:

```
<manifest>
     <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
     <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding below entry under `<plugins>` tag in pom.xml worked for me

```xml
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
```