# Manifest file in target Folder spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, manifest

Want to know how does the Manifest.mf file gets generated?

My application generates the target folder and does not create the manifest file inside of META-INF folder, but it DOES create a file when in META-INF when I unzip the war file. How can I generate the file in target/ssodconfigservice/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

[image: Manifest]

Comment: Do you use maven?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46198001/maven-is-not-creating-meta-inf-for-spring-boot-project

Comment: Yes I am using maven

Comment: Follow the link with similar question answered

Comment: It does not solve the issue